# Elasticsearch query is not returning a total value of a summed field

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-amplify-cli

I have the following elasticsearch query. It's being executed as part of AWS Amplify serverless backend.

```
const elasticBody = {
    ...defaultBody,
    aggs: {
      points: {
        date_histogram: {
          field: "createdAt",
          interval: "day",
        },
        aggs: {
          points: {
            sum: {
              field: "points",
            },
          },
        },
      },
      total: {
        sum: {
          field: "points",
        },
      },
    },
  };

  const data = await search(index, elasticBody);
```

I get the following response, which is most of what I'm attempting to get, however, the 'total' value, in the lower portion of the query is not yielding a result.

I've been poring over the Elasticsearch documentation but I'm unable to find a solution.

[image]

I was expecting the following structure in the response.

```
count: x,
data: [{...}],
```

I was expecting the count to be the summed value of all the points within the returned data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [Sum Bucket Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-sum-bucket-aggregation.html) to get total sum of return bucket response. Please check below query:

```json
"aggs": {
    "points": {
      "date_histogram": {
        "field": "createdAt",
        "interval": "day"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "points": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "points"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "total":{
      "sum_bucket": {
        "buckets_path": "points>points"
      }
    }
  }
```